# SQL Server query to get previous month name in string from another month in string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get previous month name from given month name.

For example I need to get previous month as May for the given month June.
There is no date.

I tried `select CAST(Monthname-1 AS Varchar(max)) from table`

Comment: why don't you show what have you done to find a solution yourself

Comment: select CAST(Monthname-1 AS Varchar(max)) from table .From this getting error

Answer (score 2):

Because **"There is no date."**

You can convert an augmented string `{month name} + ' 01, 1980'` to a date, and then perform the date calculation

**Example**

```
 Select datename(MONTH,dateadd(MONTH,-1,convert(date,'June'+' 01,1980')))
```

**If 2012+** and potentially bogus data ... `try_convert()`

```
 Select datename(MONTH,dateadd(MONTH,-1,try_convert(date,'June'+' 01,1980')))
```

**Returns**

```
May
```

Comment: Select datename(MONTH,dateadd(MONTH,-1,cast('June'+' 01,1980' as date))) this is use ful for me.Thanks

Comment: @keerthi Happy to help. Again, since you are dealing with strings and potentially bogus data, use try_convert() if 2012

Answer (score 1):

Add -1 months to your starting date, then use `DATENAME(month)` to get its name.

```
DATENAME(month, DATEADD(month, -1, <yourDateField>))
```

Comment: Will this work based on OP's description that there is no date? He/She needs to get the previous month when passed a string of a month name?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
SELECT DATENAME(MM,CAST('1 June 2018' AS datetime)-1)
```